# Create story map goal for each persona?

Tags: agile, user-stories

Two different personas can create an application in the product I'm working on:

1. Administrator from within the system.
2. Guardian/parent from a portal.

When creating the story map, I started thinking about the top row "Goals".

Should the goal be connected to one persona or many? Any pitfalls?
The steps might look very different depending on the persona.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, each persona has distinct needs and expectations from the application so separate goals for each is the right way to go. You might find some goals overlap, especially NFRs, and can draw them out into overall goals for the application.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal for each persona with undoubtedly be different, the administrator will have a different persona with reference to his access and functions within the product. The Parent/Guardian persona will also be built according to why you want them to use the product, the desired outcome and the steps to be taken to achieve your established outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two distinct user personas, you will require two separate user stories. Each user persona has a different description and the goals are different.
You can have something like 'As an administrator, I want to be able to...' and 'As a parent, I want to be able to.....'

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what the others have already said, it may very well be that "from within the system" and "from a portal" lead to different requirements/implementation details/interfaces etc. So yes indeed.